# Occurrence of a string in all the file names within a folder in Bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, glob

I am trying to make a script which allow me to select files with 2 or more occurrences of a string in their name.

Example:

```
test.txt      // 1 occurrence only, not ok
test-test.txt // 2 occurrences OK
test.test.txt // 2 occurrences OK
```

I want the script to return me only the files 2 and 3. I tried like that but this didn't work:

```
rows=$(ls | grep "test")
for file in $rows
do
        if [[ $(wc -w $file) == 2 ]]; then
                echo "the file $file matches"
        fi
done
```

Comment: the idea was to get the number of occurrences using grep -c  then to use wc -w   in order to compare the number of words with the number of lanes  (matching files should have wc -l  = 2  and grep -c = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` and `wc` are overkill. A simple glob will suffice:

```
*test*test*
```

You can use this like so:

```
ls *test*test*
```

or

```
for file in *test*test*; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: this indeed works, i only wondered if i could find a more generic way without have to specify the number of occurrences.   I meant a way to manipulate the grep output in order to get the number of occurrences in there

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

`result=$(grep -o "test" yourfile | wc -l)`

**-wc** is a word count

In shell script if `$result>1` do stuff...